# Getting space-separated numbers from a file in Java

Tags: java

Here is my input file. I want to make an int array from it:

```
3 5 1 5 7 1 10 1 6 10 6 2 1 2 0 5 8 1
```

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yes.txt"));
String s = in.readLine();
int[] score = new int[s.length()];
for(int j=0;j<s.length();j+=2){
    score[j] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(j));
}
```

I am not getting the desired output. Please help me.

Expected output:

```
score[0] = 3, score[1] = 5 and so on
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: some undesired value...

Answer (score 3):

Your code assumes that all the input numbers would have a single digit, butr you input example includes a two digit number - 10.

I suggest you take a different approach :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yes.txt"));
String s = in.readLine();
String[] strScores = s.split(" ");
int[] score = new int[strScores.length];
for(int j=0;j<strScores.length;j++){
    score[j] = Integer.parseInt(strScores[j]);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the use of Character.getNumericValue here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of coding for a fixed number width, use a [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) call:

```
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
int[] score = new int[parts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
    score[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
```